# Correctly set R default graphic device to quartz?

Tags: r

I tried to add the following line in my `.Rprofile` file:

```
options(device = quartz)
```

It produced an error:

```
Error in options(device = quartz) : object 'quartz' not found
```

Then I tried:

```
options(device = "quartz")
```

And it works.

However, both work in the regular `R` session. Can anyone tell me what is the reason for the difference in behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The erro message says it all. There is no data-object named 'quartz' and the `options` function is not expecting (nor can it find) a function name as an argument value for  the 'device'-node.

You are seeing the effect of the environment where `.Rprofile` is being evaluated because some of the usual packages (such as stats or graphics) are not yet loaded. Read more about this at `?Startup`. You could avoid this by starting .Rprofile with `require(grDevices)`

Comment: Thanks! The document says when `.Rprofile` is evaluated, only `base` package is loaded, but `quartz()` function is in `grDevices`.